# how to eliminate duplicates but keep the document with more fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, duplicates, robo3t

I have the following query:
I have duplicate documents but I need to eliminate them, but keeping the document with the largest fields in mongodb.
The repeating field is "financialAccount" I managed to make a query but in some cases it deletes the document that I don't want.
Could you help me with this please.
Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhjqg.png)

I need to keep the document with larger fields and remove the other duplicates.

Comment: can you add text query and documents in question instead of image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to use the highDate field as a filter to be able to remove the record.
Only the record with the oldest "highDate" field remains.

```
 bulk  = db.financialAccount.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
count = 0;
db.financialAccount.aggregate([
    { '$sort': { 'createDate': 1 }}, 
    {  $match : { financialAccount: {"$in":[
        '548541000'
     ]}}},
    { '$group': { '_id': '$financialAccount', 'ids': { '$push': '$_id' }, 'count': { '$sum': 1 },'financialAccount':{'$first': "$financialAccount"}}}, 
    { '$match': { 'count': { '$gt': 1 }}}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.ids.shift();
    bulk.find({'_id': { '$in': doc.ids }}).remove(); 
    count++; 
    if(count === 100) { 
        bulk.execute(); 
        bulk = db.financialAccount.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
})

if(count !== 0) { 
    bulk.execute(); 
}
```